# How to make zend project virus free?

Tags: zend-framework

How to make Zend Project more secure ?

I am working on zend project, so what i excepting

1. it should be virus free.(check it at time of uploading document).
2. free from xss attack.

Comment: you might want to add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend provides mechanism for preventing xss attack by using orm layer.

1 you can scan your project source by using anti-virus tools
for reference  http://www.sitepoint.com/zf-clamav/

2 Preventing Cross-Site Scripting Attacks

use following tips

=> Data Validation

=> Data Sanitization

=> Output Escaping

For reference http://www.sitepoint.com/php-security-cross-site-scripting-attacks-xss/

Answer (score 1):

1) "Virus free" heavily depends on what your hosting company provides (if you think host-based antivirus). Check the files on the source computer before uploading. There may even be existing programs/plugins that do this automatically.

To be more general, keep all of your code directories read-only. Do not allow the webserver process (eg apache) to write in locations where you load (include) code from. If you need such locations (cache directories etc), make them unaccessible by browsers (using .htaccess, or place them outside of your document root).

2) XSS attacks

Use $this->quote(something) in your ZF1 views, this escapes data output properly so it shouldnt get executed by the browser.

vam's answer does not protect from XSS, but SQL injection.

Generally, web application security is a subject too broad for xExchange. There are many books on the subject, even free.